# Configuring GitLab and Jenkins on different URLs

Tags: networking, server, apache2, jenkins, gitlab

I'm a newbie at configuring servers and networks and I just recently installed Ubuntu Server on an old laptop to work on. The server currently has Jenkins, GitLab and Apache2 installed.

I can successfully log-in to GitLab by going to `server.lan` - and it redirects me to `server.lan/users/sign_in` - but to access Jenkins I have to type `server.lan:8081`. I had to change the port to avoid conflicts with GitLab.

So is there a way that I can access these services by typing `server.lan/jenkins` or `server.lan/gitlab` and make them work from there? All the answers I can find is about port and IP redirection and most of them have no answers at all.

My /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       COMPAQ.lan      COMPAQ

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.1.72    server.lan
```

Thanks in advance!

Just checked this article on GitLab: `https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server` but with no luck

Comment: It's difficult to make gitlab work on `foo.bar/gitlab` instead of `foo.bar/`. You'd be better off using different domains for both: `git.server.lan`, `ci.server.lan`, but Gitlab already has a CI, so you probably don't need Jenkins at all.

Comment: @muru thanks man! I'm still learning the ropes here... I just managed to make gitlab work on `foo.bar/gitlab` but it's still listening on the port 8080. If I go to `foo.bar/jenkins` I get a 404 from gitlab, so I'm gessing I need to use something to filter the ports. I'll have to investigate more on GitLab's CI. Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For changing Jenkins Port

use

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

or

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpsPort=9090
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15265306/7111561)

This will work only temporaly (for testing). To make the change permanent do

1. `/etc/default/jenkins`
2. Find the line `HTTP_PORT=8080` and change it to your needs
3. restart jenkins `sudo service jenkins restart`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341352/7111561)

## For changing Gitlab Port

Do

1. `sudo -e /etc/gitlab gitlab.rb`
2. Change external_url from yourdomain.com to `yourdomain.com:9999`

   `9999` -> Port you want it to run

   (instead of changing the port here you could also try to directly add the path like `yourdomain.com/gitlab` but I'm not sure this works)
3. `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

[Source](https://serverfault.com/a/608093/410783)

Note: 
I would prefer changing the Jenkins port because more usual user want to access Gitlab just by entering the domain name maybe while for Jenkins probably only few administrators need access. Let those use the domain+port or domain/jenkins if you prefer so.

Comment: Just finished configuring that. Now I can access GitLab using `server.lan` which redirects me to the GitLab login page and I changed Jenkins port to avoid conflicts so now I'm accessing Jenkins using it's port on `server.lan:8081`. Thanks @derHugo! :)

Comment: Glad to help you :) Feel free to mark the answer as accepted so people also now your questions is solved already